# Не устанавливаются Linux-системы на USB

Tags: linux, установка, live-usb

Пытаюсь установить Linux на USB-накопитель, но все не Live-дистрибутивы туда не встают. Для загрузки образа использую другую флешку, которую прошиваю через Rufus

Пытался установить `Ubuntu 22.04`, `Ubuntu 23.10`, `Fedora Workstation 39`. Все системы нормально настраиваются до самого момента установки. На одном из этапов установки прогресс останавливается, притом установщик не зависает.

Установленный ранее на этот накопитель `Tails` работал стабильно, а перед каждой установкой флешка форматировалась

Как это исправить?